# How to Support htmlAttributes Parameters in HtmlHelper Extensions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm creating HtmlHelper extension methods.  Many of the built-in framework methods support parameters like htmlAttributes (of type object) that get rendered onto the resultant HTML.  How can I provide overloads of my own methods that also support an htmlAttributes parameter without rewriting the string concatenation logic to render them as attributes on the tag?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `HtmlHelper` object has a method that converts an object into a name/value dictionary, which you can then merge into your tag as it's being built. For example, this code will generate a `<script>` tag with whatever extra attributes are passed in:

```
var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes) as IDictionary<string, object>;

TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("script");
tag.MergeAttributes(attributes);
tag.MergeAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
tag.MergeAttribute("src", scriptPath);
```

You can either provide overloads or use default values to supply a `null` value for `htmlAttributes`, which will produce an empty `Dictionary`.

(The method also sanitizes the attribute names into valid HTML attributes, etc. so it's safe to use on just about any object.)