# Adding an unknown number of htmlAttributes to a C# MVC HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

Disclaimer: I've done some research and the closest existing question I can find to what I'm trying to do is: [How to Support htmlAttributes Parameters in HtmlHelper Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669293/how-to-support-htmlattributes-parameters-in-htmlhelper-extensions)

I'm trying to write a new DatePickerFor which calls TextBoxFor with a set of custom htmlAttributes. This is purely to save me having to add the attributes each time I want to use a DatePicker.

So far, I've got:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "datepicker", data_date_weekStart = 1, data_date_format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToLower() });
    }
```

I've managed to get it to work fine. The tricky bit is when I start to add extra parameters on to my DatePickerFor. Say, for example, I wanted to have the following signature:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DatePickerFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, DateTime earliest)
```

This method should behave almost identically to the one above, but it should add another htmlAttribute for data_startDate as in:

```
return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, new { @class = "datepicker", data_date_weekStart = 1, data_date_format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToLower(), data_startDate = earliest.ToShortDateString() });
```

How could I create a method signature, and accompanying call to TextBoxFor that takes an unknown combination of parameters? Initially I might be looking to have:

- StartDate
- EndDate
- StartDate and EndDate
- StartDate and AllowWeekendSelection
- EndDate and AllowWeekendSelection
- StartDate and EndDate and AllowWeekendSelection

and so on...

I figured I could write a method signature that takes each of these parameters, and an implementation that calls TextBoxFor as above, adding in all the relevant attributes for that particular method signature. But that smells quite strongly of breaking the DRY rule.

Could anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just use optional parameters? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: And named parameters. And that overload that takes a dictionary of htmlAttributes...

Comment: I can see how to use the optional parameters in my method signature but how would I go about optionally adding those parameters into the htmlAttributes anonymous object?

Would it be a case of forgetting the anonymous object and using a RouteValueDictionary as per the other post? Is it correct that HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes() returns RouteValueDictionary?

Sorry to sound so dense, I'm still new to MVC!